# What part do I need to bypass the gearbox of a hoveround motor? Helical splined hub?

Tags: motor

I have an old powered wheelchair motor from a Hoveround.  I have removed the gearbox and I would like to attach a lawnmower blade directly to the shaft.

As you can see from the photo, it has 7 helical splines.  Am I correct in assuming that I need a helical splined hub to mesh with it, which would either have a threaded shaft on the other side to hold the mower blade, or a method by which a threaded shaft can be connected?

If that's not the name of the part I need, what would it be?  I've looked at many stores (McMaster, Servo City, etc) but can't seem to find something like this, which makes me think I am calling it the wrong thing.

FYI, the motor specs are:

- Brand: Shihlin
- Type: A9Y1X02872
- Part #: M19004442
- 24V DC

Thanks for any help.

[image: Helical splined rod]

## ServoCity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a helical pinion to me, rather than a splined shaft.  It should mesh with a helical gear in the gearbox.

So either you mesh it with a suitable gear (I can't tell enough from a photo to specify what, but the corresponding gearbox will obviously contain one), or hard-turn it down in a lathe and key it to take something else.